# Swift - Use AppDelegate in a swift class

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, bridging-header

I added a swift class to an Objective-C project, I need to access the AppDelegate.h in this class, I tried to add `#import "AppDelegate.h"` to the bridging header in order to be able to use it.

But Ì'm getting this error:

> failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../PrecompiledHeaders/Bridging-Header-swift.pch' for bridging header 'path to bridging header/Bridging-Header.h'.

I checked the path to the bridging header in Build Settings, and it's correct. I tried clean and build, deleted derived data but nothing worked. Am I using a bad practice to access the app delegate because I'm new to Objc?

Thanks

Comment: Does your target name have any special characters like - etc?

Comment: @Satheeshwaran no it does not.

Comment: UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate is throwing any error?

Comment: @Satheeshwaran yes Cannot find type 'AppDelegate' in scope

Comment: Is the bridging header generated in the path or not?

Comment: Can you please clarify in what path?

Comment: path to bridging header/Bridging-Header.h - was the file generated in that path? Whenever you add a Swift file to an Objective C folder Xcode automatically prompts you to add the bridging header did you do that? If not you can add one yourself and add it to the build settings...

Comment: Xcode created it when I added the swift file.